# How do I complete the Lava Leap badass challenge in the Crisis Scar map?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Description of the challenge says *Jump the lava river from the top of the Comms Facility.*  I don't know where you could climb that would let you jump the lava river, so any tips would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this video which shows the takeoff point from a tower *beside* the comms satellite tower!